# My App crashes with Flurry

Tags: ios, crash, flurry

I am having a little problem with flurry.
I am trying to integrate the sdk in my IOS app and when the application goes in background 
it crashes.This happens only if i start the Flurry session.
It is a sprite kit game but the sprite kit part starts later in my app and my app crashes whether the sprite kit started or not .
This is the error : gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient ().

Can you tell me what is happening?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1766/_index.html ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321477/spritekit-crashing-on-entering-background-with-flurry-startsessionflurryappkey ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set "Library Search Path" in Build Settings of Target for "$(SRCROOT)/AppNameFolder/Flurry" ?

Just add these 2 lines in main delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m

```
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
[Flurry startSession:@"Key Goes Here"];
```

Regards.